# How to add typescript type to an array into function argument?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a problem with defining array type:
Code below perfectly works:

```
const messageCustomStyles: Array<keyof IAlertMessage> = [
            'font',
            'margin',
            'padding'
        ];
return getCustomStylesFrom(styles, 'message', messageCustomStyles);
```

what I want to do is to move this array into function argument with its type, like so:

```
return getCustomStylesFrom(
  styles, 
  'message', 
  ['font', 'margin', 'padding']: Array<keyof IAlertMessage>);
```

But this throws ts error saying 'Expected 3 arguments, but got 4.' Looks like after ':' it is counting type as a new parameter.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
return getCustomStylesFrom(
  styles, 
  'message', 
  ['font', 'margin', 'padding'] as Array<keyof IAlertMessage>);
```

Comment: I tried this but then there is a problem with this approach, when I pass 4th element in array like 'test', then it doesn't throw ts error. (test is not a property of IAlertMessage interface)

Comment: actually you don't need to pass the type at all there. Because I guess your method `getCustomStylesFrom ` has a signature like this: `(style: any, message: string, arr : Array<keyof IAlertMessage>)`. So the typing is already there, no?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this function `getCustomStylesFrom` is being imported to components ts file. and it will be used in many components so it needs to be dynamic.
functions signature looks like this `getCustomStylesFrom(
    styles: Partial<IStyles<any>>,
    propertyName: string,
    stylesToGet: Array<string>
)`

Comment: I don't think this is possible then. You could do some functions to iterate over the interface's properties but it won't look as clean as your working example there.